# upgrading to 16.04 problems

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

My system, custom build about 5 years ago;
Thermaltake V3 case;
Asrock 880G Motherboard;
AMD Phenom(tm) II X2 555 Processor × 2
1 Tb HDD (sata)
4G Ram.

I started my Ubuntu life with 12.04LTS, upgraded to 13.10 trying to fix problems, clean install 14.04LTS in a separate partition as soon as it was released, it was still problematic,shortly after this my circumstances changed and the computer has been in storage for 2 years.

Booting into the system gave me a couple of options, I chose the first Ubuntu option and booted into the problematic 14.04lts,  tried doing the uprade to 16.04 but failed so in my haste to get it up and running chose the 16.04 server iso instead of desktop which I tried to install on an empty partition but it stopped at “determining GRUB boot device” (33%).
Can someone please point me in the right direction??

update; I managed to boot into the old 13.10 system and is still usable so will move some personal stuff around, backup and do a clean install of 16.04.

Comment: If I install the server iso how hard is it to upgrade to desktop??

Answer (score 0):

Sure, first of all, you should be able to install a regular graphical environment after installing the server based ISO.

If you can log into a recovery environment, first choose the networking option to mount your system in read write mode. Then, choose the root prompt option and run the following commands:

```
apt-get update 
apt-get install tasksel
tasksel
```

This should give options for installing a desktop environment.

If you cannot boot due to the grub error, you should reinstall grub from a live DVD or USB in a chroot environment or just use boot repair if you are not sure how to do that.